# NoReverseMatch at /api/login/social/jwt-pair/

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I was following the documentation on drf social auth https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth/tree/master

I've encountered an issue while working with Django-Rest-Social-Auth and Simple-JWT. The error message is as follows:

```
NoReverseMatch at /api/login/social/jwt-pair/facebook/
'http' is not a registered namespace
```

I've registered my path in the root urls.py (located in the config folder) as follows:

```
path("api/login/", include("rest_social_auth.urls_jwt_pair"))
```

Despite referring to the documentation, I'm unable to resolve this error. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into what might be causing this problem. Could someone kindly assist?

Comment: Show view code which handles this request `/api/login/social/jwt-pair/facebook/` you have somewhere `redirect` or other function with `http://...` view reference which is an error. You should refer to url pattern names, not URLs themselves. And show other url patterns included in this urls.py

Comment: The views are present in the urls_jwt_pair package by using Ctrl+click